# Jquery filter array of object with loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects like this:

```
myArray = [
{label: "a", 
value: "100"},
{label: "b",
value: "101"},
{label: "c",
value: "102"}
...
```

I want to filter it like this:

```
myArrayFiltered = myArray.filter(function(v){ 
    return v["value"] == "101" || v["value"] == "102"});
```

Which will return

```
myArrayFiltered = [
{label: "b",
value: "101"},
{label: "c",
value: "102"}]
```

in this example but I want to do the filter with an array of values. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check if the value you're filtering on is in your array

```
myArrayFiltered = myArray.filter(function(v){ 
    return ["102", "103"].indexOf(v.value) > -1;
});
```

Comment: This one works. Don't forget to add ); at the end.
In fact I wasn't using an array to filter but an array of objects like the first array. I converted it in an array to get only the values and then use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method inside your filter:

```
var requiredValues = ["101", "102", "103"];
myArrayFiltered = myArray.filter(function(v){ 
    return requiredValues.some(function(value) {
        return value === v.value;
    });
});
```

Comment: You can pass `requiredValues` as the second parameter into `.filter(callback[, thisArg])` and then use `this.indexOf()`. Then you won't have to rely on a "global" parameter - [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @Andreas Certainly possible. I prefer this approach, as it feels unnatural to pass in a variable and pass it off as *context*, so I'll leave this as-is.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrValues = ["101", "102"];



 var result = getData(arrValues,"102")



 function getData(src, filter) {
        var result = jQuery.grep(src, function (a) { return a == filter; });
        return result;
    }
```