# Angular / Javascript search array for object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

For the purpose of example lets have the following object:

```
var myobj = {id: 1, text: 'hello world', user_id: 5}
```

Now lets say we have an array:

```
var objectContainer = []
```

And we fill this objectContainer with x number of `myobj`

Now we wish to find the `myobj` that has the `id` value set to `30`

You could use a loop but in worst case you would have to loop through the whole array before finding your value.

So my question is does `JaVaScript` have a function for these situations or does `AngularJs`provide additional helpers to solve this?

Comment: see [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @Hacketo can this be used to retrieve the item in a controller / service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of different solutions :

1. Javascript FIND : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
   Example :
   `var myobject = objectContainer.find(function(value){ return value.id === 1; });`
2. Angular filter : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter
3. If your ids are unique you could also use a **map** instead of an array :

Exemple :

```
var myobj = {id: 1, text: 'hello world', user_id: 5};

var objectContainer = {};

objectContainer[myobj.id] = myobj;
```

*etc*

Comment: `find` is es6 . Also you should provide english links on StackOverflow.

Comment: Indeed but you can still provide an implementation of `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Your value of 'x' is the array indexer. So objectContainer[29] should point to the myobj in the 30th position.

Comment: Yeah that would be true if you put them in cronologicly but if you put them in at random this would not

Comment: try Array.findIndex("what you want to search);

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31005792/1986006) of finding objects in an array.
But still it will loop over all elements of an array.