# Merge array of objects in efficient way

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have below scenario where I am trying to merge two array of objects.

The current code works, but I am looking for a more efficient way.

```js
var constList = [
  { name: "jack", id: "1", designation: "hr" },
  { name: "mary", id: "2", designation: "it" },
  { name: "john", id: "3", designation: "fin" }
]

var apiList = [
  { name: "jack", id: "1", height: "10" },
  { name: "mary", id: "2", height: "20" }
]

var temp = [];

constList.forEach(x => {
  apiList.forEach(y => {
    if (x.id === y.id) {
      temp.push({ ...x,
        ...y
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log(temp);
```

Only the matching elements from apiList should be merged with constList.

The output is correct, can anyone guide me with best way to to it.

Comment: define what you mean by "a more efficient way"

Comment: I fail to find fault with your logic as written.  If it works, go with it.  Don't "worry" a piece of code unless you are truly confronted with a human-measurable problem that *must* be dealt with  As Perl programmers like to say, "Tim Toady" = `TMTOWTDI` = "There's More Than One Way To Do It."  :-)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com would be more suitable for this type of question, imho

Comment: I mean can it be achieved with singel foreach or map ?

Comment: Maybe "map" would do it, maybe not.  And "Map" might wind up being really no faster.

Comment: Is any of the two lists always a subset (in terms of `id`) of the other?

Comment: There are many questions about this already; did none of the answers on those questions meet your efficiency requirements?

Comment: @user804401 you won't be able to achieve the desired outcome with a single loop.

Comment: It could be equal or subset

Comment: see the post here (comment from 'Andy') for an alternative approach using `filter` and `some` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005396/filter-array-of-objects-with-another-array-of-objects

Comment: The complexity is currently O(m*n) where m and n are the lengths of the lists. This could be reduced by making a hash based lookup like a set, but this won’t necessarily be faster in javascript unless the arrays are quite large.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects)

Comment: @user804401 ... *"It could be equal or subset"*: which one of the two could be subset of the other?

Comment: apiList will be the subset

Comment: I note that in your code you do not actually *merge* (the title has mislead me), but you take an intersection. Is it on purpose that you did not include in `temp` *all* the entries from `constList`?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is quite OK. Only for *very* large lists you could benefit from the better time complexity you get from creating a hash map. For instance with a `Map`:

```js
let constList = [{ name: "jack", id: "1", designation: "hr" },{ name: "mary", id: "2", designation: "it" },{ name: "john", id: "3", designation: "fin" }]
let apiList = [{ name: "jack", id: "1", height: "10" },{ name: "mary", id: "2", height: "20" }]

let map = new Map(constList.map(o => [o.id, o]));
let result = apiList.map(o => ({...map.get(o.id),...o}));

console.log(result);
```

This assumes that `apiList` never has any `id` that does *not* occur in `constList` (which is what you confirmed in comments).

The time complexity is *O(n+m)* here, instead of the *O(nm)* you get from the nested loop.

#### Intersection

The above assumes you really wanted to do a *merge*. I do note however that in your code you do not actually *merge* the two, but you take the *intersection*. If that is what you really wanted (*intersection*), then reverse the roles of the two arrays in the above code, like so:

```js
let constList = [{ name: "jack", id: "1", designation: "hr" },{ name: "mary", id: "2", designation: "it" },{ name: "john", id: "3", designation: "fin" }]
let apiList = [{ name: "jack", id: "1", height: "10" },{ name: "mary", id: "2", height: "20" }]

let map = new Map(apiList.map(o => [o.id, o]));
let result = [];
for (let o of constList) {
    let match = map.get(o.id);
    if (match) result.push({...o, ...match});
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what are the implications of converting an array to a `Map`? I would presume this would also affect the time complexity. I still can't see how this would be "more efficient" than the original solution proposed.

Comment: You do not match the expected output.

Comment: @sjahan, yes the OP asked for a merge, but their code is in fact doing an intersection. I have added a section (pun unintended) to my answer to do an intersection.

Comment: @DanStarns, the idea of the map is to avoid a nested loop. It represents a loop, but because it isn't nested it will give a better time complexity. A loop of a loop is not the same as a loop + a loop. The latter will be more efficient when the number of iterations is significant. Note that a Map is built in linear time, and an item can be retrieved by its key in constant time.

Comment: Extra parenthesis on the end of `result.push` there

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, @chazsolo. Corrected my last faulty edit.

Comment: @trincot cool, thanks for your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use simple for loop that could increase performance by 10x if used under certain conditions.

As I tested the below code

**TEST CASE 1**:

**Algorithim**: YOUR CODE WITH FOR EACH

**INPUT SIZE**: 150 elements (constList = 100 elements & apiList = 50 elements)

**INPUT TYPE**: apiList will always match completely with constList. i.e., All 50 elements of apiList will match with 50 elements of constList out of 100 elements.

and measure performance with your code it took **~0.81ms** to merge and sort the results.

**TEST CASE 2**:

**Algorithm**: BELOW CODE

**INPUT SIZE**: 1700 elements (constList = 1000 elements & apiList = 700 elements)

**INPUT TYPE**: apiList will always match completely with constList, i.e., All 700 elements from apiList will match with 700 elements of constList out of 1000 elements.

and measure performance with below code it took **~0.82ms** to merge and sort the results.

```js
for(let i =0; i< constList.length;i++){
    flag = true;
    for(let j=0; j<apiList.length;j++){
        if(apiList[j].id == constList[i].id){
            const data = Object.assign({}, constList[i], apiList[j]);
            temp.push(data);
            flag = false;
            apiList.splice(j,1);
            break;
        }
    }
    flag && temp.push(constList[i]) && constList.splice(i,1);
}
```

**Note:** Here, the original array will be changed due to deletion operation. So make sure to perform the operation only over clone/duplicate array to preserve original data.