# How to create new JS array from another JS array

Tags: javascript

I want to create new JS array from an object. I explained my scenario as below.

Array 1:

```
const arr1 = [
  {CODE: "PPM", YARN: 1987, EXP: "IUYT", CARD: "MMN"},
  {CODE: "SSW", YARN: 4500, EXP: "NBVC", CARD: "MMN"},
  {CODE: "YTR", YARN: 0740, EXP: "NBVC", CARD: "MMN"},
  {CODE: "NNH", YARN: 1540, EXP: "MHYT", CARD: "MMN"}
]
```

Array 2:

```
const arr2 = [
  {PRICE: 6354, CODE: "SSW", WARN: "NBVC"},
  {PRICE: 8637, CODE: "NNH", WARN: "MHYT"},
]
```

Expected output:

```
output = [
  {CODE: "SSW", YARN: 4500, EXP: "NBVC", CARD: "MMN"},
  {CODE: "NNH", YARN: 1540, EXP: "MHYT", CARD: "MMN"}
]
```

Explanation:

I want to compare `arr1` and `arr2`. If `arr1.code` contain `arr2.code` it should be in new array. It means `arr1.code[2] = 'SSW'`. `SSW` contains in `arr2.code[0]`. Then `arr1.code[2]` should be in new array. It same to `arr1.code[3] = 'NNH'`. `NNH` contains in `arr2.code[1]`.

Tried code:

```
console.log(arr1.filter(({ CODE: code1 }) => arr2.some(({ CODE: code2 }) => code2 === code1));
```

When I tried to above code I am getting an error

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined"

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `price` isn't doesn't appear in your code. Also, js is case sensitive

Comment: @ChayimFriedman yeah `js is case sensitive` I fixed it in code. How can I skip `PRICE` and consider only `CODE`

Comment: Your code works when I run it, only add `)` in the end of it

Comment: @aer-der What do you mean by "skip `PRICE`"?  Where are you even using `PRICE` in your code?

Comment: @Ravid can you please post it in jsfiddle. Because It not gives a output for me

Comment: Please make sure the error is consistent with the code you provide.

Comment: What kind of syntax is `({ CODE: code1 }) => ...`?  I've never seen that before...

Comment: @RocketHazmat, it is a destructuring of a property and a renaming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of objects with another array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005396/filter-array-of-objects-with-another-array-of-objects)

Comment: @aer-der This code contains your example and it is working an printing correct result in console: https://jsfiddle.net/8enugf3z/

Comment: @RocketHazmat Take a look at [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration)

Comment: @Gunther Cool, thanks!  Didn't know that was a feature JavaScript added.  Super-cool :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const arr1 = [
  {CODE: "PPM", YARN: 1987, EXP: "IUYT", CARD: "MMN"},
  {CODE: "SSW", YARN: 4500, EXP: "NBVC", CARD: "MMN"},
  {CODE: "YTR", YARN: 0740, EXP: "NBVC", CARD: "MMN"},
  {CODE: "NNH", YARN: 1540, EXP: "MHYT", CARD: "MMN"}
]

const arr2 = [
  {PRICE: 6354, CODE: "SSW", WARN: "NBVC"},
  {PRICE: 8637, CODE: "NNH", WARN: "MHYT"},
]

console.log(arr1.filter(({
    CODE: code1
}) => arr2.some(({
    CODE: code2
}) => code2 === code1))**)**;
```

I guess you might have missed a bracket **)** in the **console.log** statement. But still, you have not used the **price** keyword in the code. Might be some other issue. Can you please share the full function?