# filter an array based on values of another array in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

if I have an array looking as the following:

```js
names: [{
  value: 'recordedData',
  desc: 'Data'
} {
  value: 'recordedNumbers',
  desc: 'numbers'
} {
  value: 'recordedNames',
  desc: 'names'
}]
```

and another array looking as the following:

```js
displayed: [{
  value: 'data',
  desc: 'Data'
} {
  value: 'numbers',
  desc: 'numbers'
}]
```

I want to filter the first array based on the second array so I would have the following resulted array :

```js
DisplayedNames: [{
  value: 'recordedData',
  desc: 'Data'
} {
  value: 'recordedNumbers',
  desc: 'numbers'
}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of objects with another array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005396/filter-array-of-objects-with-another-array-of-objects)

Comment: nope , I have checked the answers but none of them is typescript and most of them not working

Comment: `names.filter(el => displayed.some(f => f.desc === el.desc))` doesn't do what you expect? (Also, TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. JavaScript solutions should work fine within TypeScript and there is little TS can add here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Array.prototype.some()` is an elegant way to achieve this

```js
const names = [{value: 'recordedData', desc: 'Data'},
 {value: 'recordedNumbers', desc: 'numbers'},
 {value: 'recordedNames', desc: 'names'}];
 
const displayed = [{
  value: 'data',
  desc: 'Data'
}, {
  value: 'numbers',
  desc: 'numbers'
}]

 const result = names.filter(x => displayed.some(y => y.desc === x.desc));
 
 console.log(result);
```

More about `Array.prototype.some()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some
More about `Array.prototype.filter()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter